# when use gpio_set_value, i can't get gpio state with gpio_get_value later

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, delay, interrupt, gpio

I'm learning how to setup key-interrupt with generic gpio. But there is problem that i can't understand what's wrong with my code.

```
gpio_is_valid(mygpio);
gpio_request(mygpio);
gpio_direction_output(……);
……
```

It's simple setting with the gpio-pin. Then I register an interrupt handler.In interrupt handler, I use the tasklet.
  BUT! Strange thing happened! As follow:

```
gpio_set_value(mygpio, 1);
```

considered about that the hardware need time to run and set, so even I insert `mdelay(100)` here. After that invoke `gpio_get_value(mygpio)`, the return is 0, zero!!! 
   At last, I disabled all interrupt and do above again.But nothing has changed. What's wrong happened??

Comment: I;m not quite sure what you are trying to achieve.
After GPIO is locked as interrupt source you don't need to check it's value. Proper flags will assure that interrupt happens and there will be no interrupt flood.

Comment: Thanks anyway for you answer. I'm so sorry for that I do not notice it wiht long time.
Actually, I'm just want to add log to make sure it sets ok. Because after setting high-level, only the gpio-pin'voltage is too small in my hardware board. It comes 0.3V, but someohters' performance is normal that can be 3.3V.
The BUG has been existed. Unfortunately, what can i do is just changing another gpio-pin. So sad.

Comment: Update your post with the bug description, but for me it sounds like misconception of GPIO and GPIO-as-IRQ.

Comment: Yet!  U are right, but i'm a novice of Linux and the kernel too. It's little harder for me to understand how the whole system work. I just know, when gpio-input, it's usually used for intterupt and output used for drivering some hardware devices.But i'm so glad that the kind people like u can help me.